# How can i SELECT sum() many columns in 1 query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Just Sample Table : Cus_fi.

[image]

Can i

```
SELECT SUM(dollar,euro,pound) FROM cus_fi ; in 1 query.
```

And Show Result by age range like this.

```
   20 - 25   1500    410     166
   26 - 30   5300    2000    584
```

Thank for  help student really want to known.

Comment: He already shared his query

Comment: I hope for you `age` is a calculated column...

Comment: No, i just prepare resource to do report and learn together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
SELECT age, SUM(dollar) AS Total_Dollar, SUM(Euro) AS Total_Euro, 
SUM(Pound) AS Total_Pound 
    FROM cus_fi GROUP BY age
```

EDIT:

```
SELECT CONCAT(2*floor(age/2), '-', 2*floor(age/2) + 2) as `age_range`, SUM(dollar) AS Total_Dollar, SUM(Euro) AS Total_Euro, 
SUM(Pound) AS Total_Pound 
    FROM cus_fi GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY age
```

Comment: Closer. Thank you very much. How about age range ?

Comment: Yeah, awesome answer. Thanks for waste the time.

Comment: You're welcome and it is not a waste, it is a pleasure for me to help someone :)

Answer (score 3):

```
select
    round(age / 5) * 5 - 4,
    round(age / 5) * 5,
    SUM(dollar),
    SUM(euro)
FROM TEST
GROUP BY round(age / 5)
```

You can extend it with more columns. See DEMO: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/160bb/15

Comment: concat first two expressions with an hyphen in between them.

Comment: result FROM SUM() closer than below answer. Thank.